# Setting Google Photos date

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-photos

I uploaded many photos with no EXIF data, but with their date in the name. Google Photos used upload date to sort them. I'd like to use the date in their name to modify them.

So far I tried to use Drive API to change modification date, I can change it but it is not used. I also tried to modify imageMediaMetadata.date, but it seems to be read-only to me.

Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("IMG-20150402-WA0002_1.jpg")
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var name = file.getName().toUpperCase();
    if (name.indexOf("-WA") > -1) {
      if (name.indexOf("IMG-20") == 0 || name.indexOf("VID-20") == 0) {
        var y = name.substr(4, 4);
        var m = name.substr(8, 2);
        var d = name.substr(10, 2);

        var file2 = Drive.Files.get(file.getId());
        file2.imageMediaMetadata.date = y+"-"+m+"-"+d+"T12:00:00.000Z";
        var file3 = Drive.Files.patch(file2, file.getId());
        Logger.log(name + " no ok " + file3.imageMediaMetadata.date);  // same as file2
      }
    }
  }
```

I could delete them, modify the original files and re-upload, but before that I'd like to be sure there is no other way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could programmatically write an EXIF header to the files?

I would also be looking for a convenient way to supply photo date when uploading old photos using the new-ish Google Photos API. My photos do not necessarily have EXIF data; I tried setting the creation/last modified date on one of my JPEGs on my MacOS machines disk, then manually uploading it via the Google Photos *web interface* and the date of of the JPEG file on local disk becomes the photo's date in Google Photos, as expected. The file has no EXIF data and if did, it would not contain that same date, so apparently the google photos web uploader respects the local filesystem date for the photo.

I then tried to sniff the traffic using Charles Proxy, but apparently the web interface does not use the Google Photos API same way that us external developers would -- it doesnt POST to https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads or so it seems. So I couldn't reverse engineer that process. Also I couldn't see where the file creation date was passed in.

What would be great is to have a HTTP header in the upload POST request to set this date. I dont see batchCreate (https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/batchCreate) method having any means of setting this.